# Suitable label to opt-out of beta

Tags: copywriting

My company is testing out a new writing recommendation tool that will help users write better blog posts. The recommendation panel will appear next to the "body" input field, which is one field in a larger form.

It's been decided that this will be released as a beta, with an option to opt-out and return to the standard layout. Unfortunately, due to technical reasons, once a user has decided to opt-out they won't be able to opt back in. The transition from the beta view to the standard view is seamless. Any text a user has already entered will remain, but the recommendations panel and text highlighting will disappear.

The issue I'm having is thinking of an appropriate label for the opt-out link. I'm currently using **"Hide recommendations"**, but I'm worried users might think this means that they can hide and show the recommendations at will. I thought about something simple like **"Exit beta"**, but again, I'm concerned that users might think they'll be taken away from the form.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ask is quite heavy for copy to solve on its own. Here are some potential UI approaches that could support clarifying the copy challenge you are facing - ordered by assumed LOE low to high - and many of which can be combined:

- Save & Hide Recommendations - Feels wonky but at least removes the worry their progress will be lost
- Add a simple ? or (i) hover icon next to Hide Recommendations that explains it's a beta feature and can be exited, work will be saved but the user cannot opt back in
- Same recommendation as above, but at a global level (like a very slim banner message at the top of the page) vs in the recommendation panel
- Use a BETA tag in the header of the recommendation panel. On click of the BETA tag the user can see information about the beta and opt-out.
- Require an opt-out confirmation when Hide Recommendations is clicked. The opt out can communicate that 1) work will not be lost and 2) user cannot opt back in - this is also your opportunity to ask why they are turning off the beta.
- (Combine this recommendation with one above) On landing in the experience for the first time, display an overlay explaining the beta and that they can leave any time, but wont be able to get it back (show the UI in the overlay)
- Make the beta an opt-in first, with an overlay promoting the beta and allowing the opt in, communicating here that an exit is permanent until the final version release. Then be sure to find a way to indicate that the user is viewing the BETA version (either top banner or any of the suggestions above)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a label, that is something more natural language like this - 
"Do Not Show Recommendations Panel" or "Disable Recommendations" as a checkbox at the top of the panel or at a suitable position. Once the user checks it - you can show a confirmation dialogue that informs the user that they will not be able to get back this beta feature if disabled once and that their current work will not be hampered. Once confirmed, you can swiftly hide the panel.